Flutter build fail. Kotlin version not compatible
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of the metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Had to update the Kotlin version is the build Gradle 2 weeks ago to fix a different problem and has been running successfully until today with some deprecation warning error
nothing successful found online to remedy the problem
